# Vuetify v-data-table with CRUD actions: dialog with dynamic forms wont work with v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-model, form-generator, v-data-table

I have a Vuetify v-data-table with CRUD actions. The table entries can be changed or deleted using form fields in a dialog. Different from the example from the manual ([Vuetify v-data-table CRUD Actions](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#crud-actions)) I have a form generator in the dialog. But with this the v-model="editedItem" does not work. Maybe someone can help me here. For illustration I have replicated the whole thing in a codesandbox. Here is the link to the sandbox: [My Example on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-grass-94cdu)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem. So the data section of `FormBuilder` is executed once only. So first time it works fine but second time it's not executing the data section.

You need to add a `watch` on the `value` variable and assign the data in `formData` again.

You can also use `immediate:true`

Ex-

```
watch: {
  test: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal, oldVal)
    },
  },
},
```

Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-brook-em6lk

Comment: Thank you so much. That solves my problem. I was too focused on the v-model. I didn't even think about it:-(